# Need assistance with a VBS script. Getting an Object required error

Tags: vbscript, wsh

I am new to VBS scripting, and I am trying to grasp a script we currently use at work to set specific settings for workstations.

I have modified the script for our updated needs, but I am getting an error when trying to run it.

Error: Object required: 'document.getElementById(....)'

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
'******************IE Interface Starts******************************************
Public skipexit
Dim oIE      ' declare variables
Dim path
Dim oBut, oBut2
Dim ready

' *** get script path -> because form (HTML file)
' *** must be in the same folder!!!
path = WScript.ScriptFullName
path = Left(path, InstrRev(path, "\"))

' *** launch Internet Explorer ***
Set oIE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
  oIE.left = 250          ' window position
  oIE.top = 250           ' and other properties
  oIE.height = 595
  oIE.width = 530
  oIE.menubar = 0         ' no menu
  oIE.toolbar = 0
  oIE.statusbar = 0
' commented out, because it causes a corrupted window  
  oIE.resizable = 0      ' disable resizing
  oIE.navigate path & "options.php"  ' Form

  oIE.visible = 1         ' keep visible


' Important: wait till MSIE is ready
Do While (oIE.Busy)  
   WScript.Sleep 100   ' suspend, just to lower CPU load   
Loop

' now connect the event handler
Set oBut = oIE.document.getElementById ("Run")
Set oBut.onclick = GetRef ("GetFormValue")
Set oBut2 = oIE.document.getElementById ("Cancel")
Set oBut2.onclick = GetRef ("EndProgram")

'****Values

    oIE.Document.ValidForm.DisableNICpowermanagement.checked = True
    oIE.Document.ValidForm.BSODrestartDisable.checked = True
    oIE.Document.ValidForm.DisplaySettings.checked = True
    oIE.Document.ValidForm.SysTrayNoHide.checked = True
    oIE.Document.ValidForm.WindowsUpdate.checked = True
    oIE.Document.ValidForm.RDPenable.checked = True
    oIE.Document.ValidForm.USBPowerManagementDisable.checked = True
    oIE.Document.ValidForm.ServicesDisable.checked = True
    oIE.Document.ValidForm.SyncOfflineFilesDisable.checked = False

    oIE.Document.ValidForm.ShowHiddenFiles.checked = True
    oIE.Document.ValidForm.SetVirtualMem.checked = True
    oIE.Document.ValidForm.PowerManagment.checked = True
    oIE.Document.ValidForm.AddRegistryFavorites.checked = True
    oIE.Document.ValidForm.W32TimeServer.checked = True
    oIE.Document.ValidForm.ActionCenter.checked = True
    oIE.Document.ValidForm.SimpleFileSharingDisable.checked = True

'Wait until the OK button has clicked
ready = false
Do Until ready
  WScript.Sleep 100  ' supend, just to lower CPU load
Loop

oIE.Quit               ' close Internet Explorer
Set oIE = Nothing      ' reset object variable 


' ### Event handler ###
Sub GetFormValue
' User has clicked the OK button, get values
 skipexit = true
    runDisableNICpowermanagement = oIE.Document.ValidForm.DisableNICpowermanagement.checked
    runBSODrestartDisable = oIE.Document.ValidForm.BSODrestartDisable.checked
    runDisplaySettings = oIE.Document.ValidForm.DisplaySettings.checked
    runSysTrayNoHide = oIE.Document.ValidForm.SysTrayNoHide.checked
    runWindowsUpdate = oIE.Document.ValidForm.WindowsUpdate.checked
    runRDPenable = oIE.Document.ValidForm.RDPenable.checked
    runUSBPowerManagementDisable = oIE.Document.ValidForm.USBPowerManagementDisable.checked
    runServicesDisable = oIE.Document.ValidForm.ServicesDisable.checked
    runSyncOfflineFilesDisable = oIE.Document.ValidForm.SyncOfflineFilesDisable.checked
    runShowHiddenFiles = oIE.Document.ValidForm.ShowHiddenFiles.checked
    runSetVirtualMem = oIE.Document.ValidForm.SetVirtualMem.checked
    runPowerManagment = oIE.Document.ValidForm.PowerManagment.checked
    runAddRegistryFavorites = oIE.Document.ValidForm.AddRegistryFavorites.checked
    runW32TimeServer = oIE.Document.ValidForm.W32TimeServer.checked
    runSimpleFileSharingDisable = oIE.Document.ValidForm.SimpleFileSharingDisable.checked
    runActionCenterDisable = oIE.Document.ValidForm.ActionCenter.checked
```

Comment: Can you please trim your code down that only shows your problem?

Comment: Done. Sorry about that.

Comment: based on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970450.aspx) I don't think Document has a method getElementById. You have to 'build' it your self by looping over the [Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970451.aspx)

Comment: @rene The [`document`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535862) object most definitely does have a `getElementById()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Set oIE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
```

with

```
Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

and try again. Also, you're loading a `.php` file from a local path. PHP files usually contain server-side code. This may also cause problems.

As a side note, you avoid building paths by using string operations:

```
path = WScript.ScriptFullName
path = Left(path, InstrRev(path, "\"))
...
oIE.navigate path & "options.php"
```

It's more reliable to do it with the respective `FileSystemObject` methods:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
path = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
...
oIE.navigate fso.BuildPath(path, "options.php")
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, but I am still getting the same error. The main issue seems to be with 

    Set oBut = oIE.document.getElementById ("Run").

Comment: Inspect the source code of the page. Does it contain an element with the attribute `id="Run"`?

Comment: Wow, I completely overlooked that. I was using name="Run". I changed that to id="Run". That has resolved that issue. Now I'm getting an issue with Error: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'document.ValidForm'

Comment: It means what it says. The [`document`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535862) object doesn't have a property or method named `ValidForm`. If you want to refer to an element with that ID, you have to use either `document.all.ValidForm` or `document.getElementById("ValidForm")`.